# Multiple aggregate calculations using Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

I have a dataset, df1, where I would like to:

1. **Take the average of the TotalB column based upon grouping the TotalB column**.
2. I would then like to **take this new column and subtract the free value to obtain the Used value**

df1

```
date        name    rack    TotalB  freeB   
11/20/2020  a       yes     11      5   
11/20/2020  a       yes     10      5   
11/20/2020  a       yes     12      5   
11/20/2020  a       yes     10      5   
11/20/2020  b       no      5       2   
11/20/2020  b       no      5       2   
11/20/2020  b       no      6       2
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
date        name    rack    TotalB  freeB   UsedB
11/20/2020  a       yes     10.75       5    5.75
11/20/2020  b       no      5.33        2    3.33
```

**What I am doing:**

```
SELECT AVG(TotalB) AS AVG_TotalB, date, name, rack, TotalB, freeB, (AVG_TotalB - freeB) AS UsedB
FROM df1 
GROUP BY rack
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query seems pretty close.  Mostly you need to fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date, name, rack,
       AVG(TotalB) AS AVG_TotalB, freeB,
       (AVG(TotalB) - freeB) AS UsedB
FROM df1 
GROUP BY date, name, rack, freeB;
```

Note that you cannot re-use the column alias in the same `SELECT`.  You need to repeat the expression.

Comment: Ah ok I see - let me try this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert them to DECIMAL to avoid loss of the fractional parts.

```sql
DECLARE @test TABLE (dateval date,  name varchar(50), rack varchar(10),  TotalB int,  freeB int)

INSERt INTO @test
values
('11/20/2020','a','yes',     11      ,5),   
('11/20/2020','a','yes',     10      ,5),   
('11/20/2020','a','yes',     12      ,5),   
('11/20/2020','a','yes',     10      ,5),   
('11/20/2020','b','no',      5       ,2),   
('11/20/2020','b','no',      5       ,2),   
('11/20/2020','b','no',      6       ,2);

SELECT dateval,name, rack, freeB, cast(AVG(cast(totalB as decimal(5,2))) as decimal(5,2)) as TotalB, 
cast(AVG(cast(totalB as decimal(5,2))) as decimal(5,2)) - freeB as UsedB FROM @test
GROUP BY dateval,name, rack, freeB
```

```
+------------+------+------+-------+--------+-------+
|  dateval   | name | rack | freeB | TotalB | UsedB |
+------------+------+------+-------+--------+-------+
| 2020-11-20 | a    | yes  |     5 |  10.75 |  5.75 |
| 2020-11-20 | b    | no   |     2 |   5.33 |  3.33 |
+------------+------+------+-------+--------+-------+
```